# Matlab image blending

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Hey guys. I got two images from video frames. They have a certain portion of overlap. After warping one of them, I'm currently trying to blend them together. In other words, I would like to stitch them together. But I don't know how to accomplish that. Can anybody please give me some help? Thank you!
 Let's say the image data is store in 'image1_warped' and 'image2'. Appreciated your help!

Comment: Do you strictly have to do it with Matlab? Otherwise I suggest using Hugin http://hugin.sourceforge.net/ . The software is released under GPL so you may also peek into the source code and see how the magic happens.

Comment: Voting to close.  The expertise to answer this question (without the MatLab restriction) resides at http://photo.stackexchange.com/ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know algorithms off the top of my head, but I would start by having a look at [Survey of image registration techniques](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.86.8364&rep=rep1&type=pdf)